# How to choose layers in RNN (recurrent neural networks)?

Tags: neural-network, layer, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am a beginner in RNN. I am stuck upon, upon how to choose layers for the RNN model. For example - LSTM / Dense/ Dropout/Merge layers.
I know that the choice of layers depends on the data but a overview would help a lot.